# Unmarshaling Java data types using JAXB & Groovy

Tags: java, xml, groovy, jaxb, unmarshalling

I'm new to JAXB and attempting to map datatypes in a JAXB class to their Java equivalent but it always insists on returning a string.

Given the following XML:

```
<Response>
    <Label>shiftStartTime</Label>
    <Value>06:30</Value>
    <Type>Time</Type>
</Response>
```

we can see that the that the type is declared in the `<Type>` element. What I want is to have the value returned as a Joda Time LocalTime.

My code at the moment is as follows:

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType

@XmlRootElement(name="ResponseGroup")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Response {

    @XmlElement(name="Label")
    private String label

    @XmlElement(name="Value")
    private String value

    @XmlElement(name="Type")
    private String type

    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm");

    def stringTypes = ["GPS", "Static Text", "Multi-Line Text", "Value List", "Image Capture", "Signature", "Text Box"]
    def integerTypes = ["Integer"]
    def doubleTypes = ["Summary", "Calculation", "Decimal"]
    def timeTypes = ["Time"]
    def dateTypes = ["Date"]
    def booleanTypes = ["Checkbox"]

    public String getLabel() {
        return label
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type
    }

    def getValue(){

        if(stringTypes.contains(this.type)){
            return this.value.toString()
        }
        else if (integerTypes.contains(this.type)){
            return this.value.toInteger()
        }
        else if (doubleTypes.contains(this.type)){
            return Double.parseDouble(this.value)
        }
        else if (timeTypes.contains(this.type)){
            return timeFormatter.parseLocalTime(this.value)
        }
        else if (dateTypes.contains(this.type)){
            return dateFormatter.parseLocalDate(this.value)
        }
        else if (booleanTypes.contains(this.type)){
            return this.value.toBoolean()
        }
        else {
            // Hoping for the best and returning a string
            return this.value.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

I can see in the debugger that the code in the getValue() method is being run, however the result is always returned as a 'String'.
I'm clearly missing something as there must be a way in JAXB to map the Java type depending an the `<Type>` element.